# VS 2008 IDE keeps stopping on jQuery errors

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008

I just installed VS2008 on a brand new Win7 machine and have started at a new company.  I am now running the company's main project and all is well...except that, for some reason, .Net keeps breaking on some javascript errors.  This isn't in the browser (although it only happens when running IE, in this case version 8).

I'm at a loss as to where to find the option to turn off the javascript debugging in VS 2008.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is actually in IE.

Tool -> Internet Options -> Advanced

Under browsing
Check Disable Script Debugging.

Comment: At first I didn't think this worked, but I guess after a restart it finally took effect.  Maybe I had another IE instance open.  I thought I checked for it, but maybe not. Thanks DSWD!